# how to set data in DataTable from Axios getting response from multiple API and with Promise.all

Tags: javascript, api, axios, rest

I have created code with a **switch case** to call **API** by pressing the tab. and then I have a post URL with params using **Axios**. I also use **promise**. check the following code.

```
$('#myTab button').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
var tab = $(this).attr("id");
  // console.log(tab);
            
        switchtabs(tab);
        return true;
      }else{
        alert("Please select Domain Name");
        return false
      }
});
function switchtabs(tab){
          var url = '';let prm;
    switch (tab) {
        case 'second-tab':
            url = link1;
            prm = {type:'sample1', fromdate:fromdate, todate:todate, descn:info}
            console.log(url, prm);
            break;
        case 'third-tab':
            url = link2;
            prm = {type:'sample1', fromdate:fromdate, todate:todate, descn:info}
            console.log(url, prm);
            break;
        case 'fourth-tab':
            url = link3;
            prm = {type:'sample1', fromdate:fromdate, todate:todate, descn:info}
            console.log(url, prm);
            break;
        default: 
            url = link;
            prm = {type:'domainwise', fromdate:fromdate, todate:todate, descn:shop}
            console.log(url, prm);
    }
    if(typeof url !== "undefined"){
      // let prm = {type:'domainwise', fromdate:fromdate, todate:todate, descn:'1'}

 var main = axios.post(url, prm).then(function(response){
console.log(response.data)
})

Promise.all([main]).then(function(values){
 return values
 }).catch(function(err){
  console.log(err);
 })


    }
 }
```

the response data has **occurred** while tab selected. but how to add data in **dataTable** related to tab-pane. there are multiple dataTables with different **IDs** with different **headings**. I trying to add by function DataTable(). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a label below the prm. like label = "demo". and then when URL and param pass in Axios. after that I added if condition label == "demo". and my code is working.